# Backbone/Marionette with select2 v4.0, editing the tags

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jquery-select2

I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1971/) which is an extension of the Backbone/Marionette playground fiddle. I included select2 js and css files.

Is it possible to edit a tag that is not the last tag? You can edit by backspacing in the box, but it only lets you touch the last one. I would like it to act like a gmail 'to' list where you can double click on one and edit it, then it goes back to a tag on blur.

```
        this.$('#foo').select2({
            data: [{
                id: 1,
                text: "test1.com"
            }, {
                id: 2,
                text: "test2.com"
            }],
            multiple: true,
            allowclear: true,
            tags: [],
            placeHolder: "Click Here!",
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
            minimumResultsForSearch: 1
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this using just the select2 out-of-the-box functionality. But it's quite extendable, so here's what does the trick:

```
var $select2 = this.$('#foo').select2({ tags: true });

var select2 = $select2.data("select2");            
$(document.body).on("dblclick", ".select2-selection__choice", function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);

    // get the text and id of the clicked value
    var targetData = $target.data("data");
    var clickedValue = targetData.text;
    var clickedValueId = targetData.id;

    // remove that value from select2 selection
    var newValue = $.grep(select2.val(), function (value) {
        return value !== clickedValueId;
    });
    $select2.val(newValue).trigger("change");

    // set the currently entered text to equal the clicked value
    select2.$container.find(".select2-search__field").val(clickedValue).trigger("input").focus();
});
```

And a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fx1n3v9/1/), of course.

Comment: This is most of the way there, there is a fatal flaw though. If I double click on a tag, all the tags but the first one get destroyed.

Comment: Indeed, there was such a bug. I'll update the answer shortly

Comment: @Iluvatar14 I updated the answer per your comment, can you take a look now?