# Edit value on click on selected value / tag in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 4.0 for implementing multiselect and tagging functionality.
while editing the entered value i need to use backspace key, but I want edit mode when user clicks on selected value.

I tried attaching click event to entered value's li as follows which does not  work.

```
$(".select2-selection__choice").on("click", function () {
  alert("alert");
  //trigger backspace
});
```

Please help.

thanks,

Amol

Comment: Does this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130028/backbone-marionette-with-select2-v4-0-editing-the-tags) your question?